# pygame: I can't make one rectangle notice when the other comes in contact

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)
blue = (0, 0, 200)

#img = pygame.image.load("rectangle.png")

displayW = 500
displayH = 500

display = pygame.display.set_mode((displayW, displayH))
pygame.display.update()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rectSize = 40
obstacleSize = 30

FPS = 30

def left(obstaclex,obstacley):
    pygame.draw.rect(display, blue, [0, obstacley, rectSize, rectSize])

def right(rectx,recty):
    pygame.draw.rect(display, blue, [rectx, recty, rectSize, rectSize])

def middleL(obstaclex, obstacley):
    obstacleSize = -230
    obstaclex = 500
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, [obstaclex,obstacley, obstacleSize, rectSize])

def middleR(obstaclex, obstacley):
    obstacleSize = 210
    obstaclex = 0
    #display.blit(img, (obstaclex, obstacley))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, red, [obstaclex, obstacley, obstacleSize, 40])
def middle(obstaclex, obstacley):

    middleL(obstaclex, obstacley)
    middleR(obstaclex, obstacley)



def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    obstacley = 10
    obstaclex = 1

    rectx = 220
    recty = 400

    rect1 = (rectx, recty, rectSize, rectSize)


    obstacleRectX = 0
    obstacleRectY = 20

    obstacleChangeX = 0
    obstaleChageY = 0
    randrect = random.randrange(0,4)

    myRight = rectx + rectSize
    myLeft = rectx
    myTop = recty
    myBottom = recty + rectSize

    otherRight = obstaclex + obstacleSize
    otherLeft = obstaclex
    otherTop = obstacley
    otherBottom = obstacley + rectSize

    randObstacle = random.randrange(0,2)

    while not gameExit:

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

        display.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.rect(display, blue, [rectx, recty, rectSize, rectSize])

        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            display.fill(black)
            rectx = displayW/2 + 70 + rectSize
            right(rectx,recty)

        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            display.fill(black)
            rectx = displayW/2 - 170
            left(rectx,recty)

        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            display.fill(black)
            rectx = displayW/2 + 100
            right(rectx,recty)
            rectx = displayW/2 - 170
            left(rectx,recty)

        else:
            display.fill(black)
            pygame.draw.rect(display, blue, [rectx, recty, rectSize, rectSize])
            rectx = displayW/2 - 30

##        if randObstacle == 0:
##            
##            middleL(obstaclex, obstacley)
##            obstacley += 5
##            randObstacle = random.randrange(0,2)
##        elif randObstacle == 1:
##            
##            middleR(obstaclex, obstacley)
##            obstacley += 5
##            randObstacle = random.randrange(0,2)
##        elif randObstacle == 2:
##            
##            middle(obstaclex, obstacley)
##            obstacley += 5
##            randObstacle = random.randrange(0,2)


        middleR(obstaclex, obstacley)
        obstacley += 5
        collision = True
        if ((myRight < otherLeft) and (myLeft > otherRight) and (myBottom < otherTop) and (myTop > otherBottom)):
            # i replaced the OR's with AND's
            collision = False
            print collision


        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
gameLoop()
```

I am trying to make one rectangle collide with a rectangle falling down towards it, however I cannot seem to make them collide correctly. I would like to do this with an if statement and not something such as `sprite.collide()`.

This code is not very refined, I will fix it up but for the time being to help me understand the code a little more.

**This is the edited code **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this sort of thing when you are getting started is to make 8 variables (this is just pseudo code)

```
myRight = x + width
myLeft = x
myTop = y
myBottom = y + height

otherRight = x + width
otherLeft = x
otherTop = y
otherBottom = y + height
```

The easiest way is to start with a collision and try to disprove it

```
collision = True

if ((myRight < otherLeft) or (myLeft > otherRight) or (myBottom < otherTop) or (myTop > otherBottom)):
    collision = False
```

You'll have to implement this on your own, but I found it helpful when I was getting started to use the eight variables, myRight, myLeft etc because they help you understand what all the x + width actually means

Okay I'm not going to post the whole code here because it would make this comment very long. I removed the movement and a lot of the extraneous stuff that was getting in the way. You need to first calculate everything, then draw after.

Here's your game down to the bare bones with working collision:
http://pastebin.com/P0HyPGY0

Comment: Thank you! having the variables setup like that does help to understand, however i can still not get the rects to notice when they come in contact.

Comment: so implement this into your code and then post the new code in the op so I can tell you where you went wrong, and leave a comment here when you updated so I get a notification

Comment: Ok i did that. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Why did you replace the ors with ands?? They are supposed to be ors

Comment: it spammed me with "False" whenever i ran the program. but i can change them back.

Comment: This code is just way to much of a mess for me to try to discover the problem, I'm going to simplify it a lot for you and post it back in 5-10 mins

Comment: The problem is deeper then your colision system, it's the way things are drawn first then calculated after and a plethora of other issues

Comment: Ok. i look forward to finding them all out.

Comment: Ok that is alot cleaner! So i will go read over that and learn to understand it. Thank you alot!

Comment: Can you explain to me why the ors work? cause usually (from what i have learned at least) you need both the x and y boundaries to both be active at the same time.

Comment: You always need the x and y boundaries to be active at the same time. This works because we start with collision is true then try to disprove it. What this code means does is try to disprove a collision. For example, if object 1 is too far left of object 2 then we have no collision. OR if object 1 is too high above object two we have no collision, etc etc

Comment: Oh ok, i understand.